# Protractor text string wildcards

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, protractor

I'm brand new to Protractor, and I'm looking at some basic scripts that have been put together by a colleague. Basically, the script is looking for a text string on a webpage, but the whole string value is not known.

For example, he's got a script checking that the text `Severity 1 (5)` exists. However the `(5)` is a count, so could change.

How can I change the line `expect(rowElems.get(2).getText()).toBe('Severity 1 (5)');` to include a wildcard in place of the `(5)`

i.e. If the string is `Severity 1 (99)` I want this test to pass the same as if the string is `Severity 1 (100)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, apparently you can just do **`expect(rowElems.get(0).getText()).toContain('Severity 1 (');`**

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Protractor only have [partialButtonText](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.partialButtonText)  and [partialLinkText](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.By.partialLinkText)  for check the partial texts. If these text fields are links you can use partialLinkText.

I suggest you to use `expect(rowElems.get(2).getText()).toBe('Severity 1');` to test the availability of the text value and test the numeric value seperately.

Hope this helps. :)

For more information, follow [this](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.buttonText) documentation.

Comment: I don't actually care about the numeric value after the text string. and using `expect(rowElems.get(2).getText()).toBe('Severity 1');` gives an error (`Expected 'Severity 1 (2)' to be 'Severity 1'.`)

Answer (score 0):

I would just do it with pure JS:

```
var text               = rowElems.get(2).getText(),
    isSeverityCorrect  = text.indexOf('Severity 1') > -1,
    regex              = /\(([^\)]+)\)/,
    matches            = text.match(regex),
    lastMatch          = matches && matches[matches.length - 1];

// Make sure that, the "Severity 1" string is there.
expect(isSeverityCorrect).toBe(true);

// I'm gonna assume JASMINE context here.
// Basically you need to assert if the lastMatch is a number.
expect(lastMatch).not.toBeFalsy();
expect(Number(lastMatch)).not.toBe(NaN);
```